# I have to reverse the array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and i am stuck

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse(int *prr, int i)
{
    for (i = 6; i; i--)
    {
        printf("%d is reverse \n", *prr + i);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arrr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int *ptr = arrr;
    reverse(ptr, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is

```
7 is reverse
    
6 is reverse
    
5 is reverse
    
4 is reverse
    
3 is reverse

2 is reverse
```

but not 1!

Comment: `for (i = 6; i; i--)` what happens when `i == 0`? Hint: replace your entire `for` loop with `while (i--) printf("%d is reverse \n", *prr + i);`

Comment: You wrote a loop that iterates 6 times, so shouldn't expect it to print 7 values.

Comment: Huh.  I was genuinely unaware that `+` has higher preference than dereferencing.

Comment: [C Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) Precedence No. 2 is RTL Associativity.

Comment: besides you're passing `int i` to `reverse` then overwrite it right away with `i = 6`

Comment: You should also pass `reverse(ptr, 7);` -- there are `7` elements (the size of the array), not `6` and change `int reverse(...)` to `void reverse(...)` -- you are not returning a value.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My guess is the OP meant `prr[i]` there i.e. `*(prr + i)` rather than `*prr + i`.

Comment: @DanielWalker It does not.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Per the link you posted `*` is precedence 2 which comes before (binary) `+` at 4. It just happens that with OP's array the values come out the same either way ;-)

Comment: @dxiv - oh, you are correct, I withdraw that assertion `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop condition `i` is equivalent to `i != 0` (and for your specific use-case `i > 0`).

That is, the loop will end when the `i` reaches `0`, so that index will not be printed.

To be able to print the last element, you need to include it in the loop with a condition like `i >= 0`.

Answer (score 2):

While the off-by-1 question has been answered already, a slightly more idiomatic C way to write it would be to pass the array count as an argument (instead of count-1), and use pointer arithmetic (instead of indexing).

```
void reverse(int *prr, int i)
{
    for (prr += i; i--; )
    {   printf("%d is reverse \n", *--prr); }
}

int main()
{
    int arrr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    reverse(arrr, sizeof(arrr) / sizeof(arrr[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of different ways to write the function. Though as @dxiv pointed out in your comments you want `*(prr + i)` instead of `*prr + i` (which by happy mistake just happened to output the same numbers corresponding the elements `1 - 7`)

When you want to access a specific element from an array, you options are `*(ptr + index)` which is equivalent to `ptr[index]` (or for that matter `index[ptr]`).

Whenever you need to loop a certain number of times, you can simply decrement the counter, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse (int *prr, size_t nelem)
{
    while (nelem--)
        printf ("%d is reverse\n", *(prr + nelem));
}

int main()
{
    int arrr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    
    reverse (arrr, sizeof arrr/sizeof *arrr);
}
```

Another approach for reversal is a recursive function, e.g.

```
void reverse (int *prr, size_t nelem)
{
    if (nelem) {
        printf ("%d is reverse\n", *(prr + nelem - 1));
        reverse (prr, nelem - 1);
    }
}
```

or even

```
void reverse (int *prr, size_t nelem)
{
    printf ("%d is reverse\n", *(prr + --nelem));
    
    if (nelem)
        reverse (prr, nelem);    
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

The output of all are equivalent, e.g.:

```
$ ./bin/reverse_arr_fn
7 is reverse
6 is reverse
5 is reverse
4 is reverse
3 is reverse
2 is reverse
1 is reverse
```